# Move an element to a specified X,Y coordinate

Tags: javascript, yui

Using the YUI API, how to move an element to a specified X,Y coordinate.

Return true if successful, false if an error occurs.

```
function moveIt(element, x, y) {
// write code here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In YUI2, use

```
YAHOO.util.Dom.setXY('foo', [100, 100]);
```

where foo is an id, and the second argument is an array with x and y coords.

(i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/ETHYG/4/ )

Answer (score 0):

In YUI 3 use Node.setXY:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/Node.html#method_setXY